# Get screenshot before GPU apply filters

Tags: c#, screenshot

In order to program an AI for a web video game, I'd like to get a screenshot of the game. No problem, i can use GetWindowRect.

But, this method actually save a screenshot without the filters applyed by the GPU. I mean, I'd like to get real colors of the webpage, not the one I see after the GPU processing.

The form recognition is actually based on colors and I can't publish this AI if nobody gets the same colors on the screenshot.

Is there any way to do that ?

--

PinkPR

Answer (score 0):

You need to render in the same way as you render on screen but to bitmap's device context. 
Sample code to provide basic *idea* on subject:

```
            ..
            ..
            //Application of matrices and usual program flow 
            // 
            ..     

            //Get graphics from the bitmap previously created
            Graphics gc = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

            //Get device context 
            IntPtr hDc = gc.GetHdc();
            int iPixelFormat = Gdi.ChoosePixelFormat(hDc, ref pfd);
            Gdi.SetPixelFormat(hDc, iPixelFormat, ref pfd);

            IntPtr hRc = Wgl.wglCreateContext(hDc);

            //Make it current 
            if (!Wgl.wglMakeCurrent(hDc, hRc))
            {
                throw new Exception("....");
            }

            //Render to hDc
```